# How do I resize the second image on a Wordpress page without resizing the first image using css?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, resize, image-resizing

How can I resize the second (or third or fourth) image on a wordpress page without resizing any other images on the page? I have attempted using p:nth-of-type with no success.

```
.content-wrapper.with-featured-image img {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 170px;
    max-height: 1000px;
}

.content-wrapper.with-featured-image p:nth-of-type(2) img  {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: there's no difference in style for those images, they have both the same size. Also, you should post your markup structure in a minimal verifiable code example.

Comment: Have you found a way that works for you?

Answer (score -1):

`p:nth-of-type(2) img` will only affect images within the 2nd `<p>` element. You would be better off putting the pseudo-class on the `img` element itself, so it will target all images within the `content-wrapper` element.

`.page-id-1225 .content-wrapper.with-featured-image img:nth-of-type(2)`

Comment: `so it will target all images within the content-wrapper element.` this cannot be true since you don't know the HTML structure .. CSS is not generic, it woks with HTML

Comment: Temani - The CSS given is explicit, and it was within that that I was attempting to supply an answer: `.page-id-1225 .content-wrapper.with-featured-image img` targets all of the `img` elements within the element with classes of `content-wrapper` and `with-featured-image`, which is itself contained within an element of class `page-id-1225`. You don't need to see the HTML to know what the CSS is trying to do! So, kindly un-down-vote me.

Comment: well if you insist then here is a potential html strcuture where your code is wrong https://jsfiddle.net/1Lb9tb5m/1/ ... we have img inside `.content-wrapper.with-featured-image` and this one inside `.page-id-1225` ... and we always need HTML to know what the CSS is doing

Comment: Temani, that's not actually what you said! If you'd said "don't forget nth-of-type" only works on elements within the same container and we can't assume that they are", then you'd be absolutely right and I would have said "oh yes, my mistake - he should use `nth-child()` instead then.

Comment: no, both of them are also wrong ... what i said is that you cannot be sure this will work since you have not idea about the HTML whataver CSS you will be using ... when you write this `div img` means that the img is inside div but you have absolutely no idea how! direct child, inside another container, etc etc --> So CSS alone has no meaning